# How to generate Serial No in apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam

While processing my input, I want to add a new field in output JSON, which value should be auto incremented.

Ex - 
Input list

```
{"name": "Amar", "age": 10}
{"name": "Akbar", "age": 20}
{"name": "Anthony", "age": 30}
```

Output Expected After adding Serial No

```
{"No": 1, "name": "Amar", "age": 10}
{"No": 2, "name": "Akbar", "age": 20}
{"No": 3, "name": "Anthony", "age": 30}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beam process elements in parallel and does not guarantee ordering of elements.

However, if you still want to assign counter then you can use states in apache beam to maintain a counter. Reference https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Scope of a state is a key + window. So it should work fine when assigning independent counters for different sets of keys.

However, if you have small number of keys and windows then this can impact the parallelism of your pipeline.

Also, in distributed data processing, there is not much usage of such counter, it will be great if you can describe your usecase a bit more.